I can't install pyrebase
I have tried reinstalling pyrebase multiple times but I just can't import it to any project, I do not know why but this depencency keeps throwing errors.
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Rolling back uninstall of pycryptodome
  Moving to c:\users\f4bri\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages\crypto\
   from C:\Users\f4bri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\~rypto
  Moving to c:\users\f4bri\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages\pycryptodome-3.21.0.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\f4bri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\~ycryptodome-3.21.0.dist-info
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pycryptodome


I have run into this type of problem before, it is most likely because you have more than 1 version of Python or more than 1 version of pip so the pip/python version you have installed pyrebase to is not the same version you are using in your editor. What worked for me is uninstalling all of the pip and python versions from my computer including all the folders in the c drive then install a fresh copy of Python then try installing pyrebase from pip again, that should fix it.
Hope that Works.
